can short sleep lead to programming brain for greatness?
lack of sleep is one of the most worst things in life it has a lot of harms to people but there is one thing that is in disadvantage but it can be a great advantage if we used it well lack of sleep make the brain more readily to accept specific ideas and it is mean that you can use it to implant the values and ideas and programming the brain for other brain but what if we can wake up the gene which is called  DEC2 through the same idea to short sleep and implant what do we want to be and convert your self to the man that you want to be
